# UWP in-app purchase GetAddOnInfo

Tags: uwp, in-app-purchase, windows-10-universal

My app is already in the store. https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9n19jm5g8mz4

And i have create 3 add-ons in the dash board.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjv8R.png)

But i cant get any info from the following code, why?

queryResult.Products.count is 0!!!

`

```
public async Task GetAddOnInfo()
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
            }

            // Specify the kinds of add-ons to retrieve.
            string[] productKinds = { "Durable" };
            List<String> filterList = new List<string>(productKinds);

            StoreProductQueryResult queryResult = await context.GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync(productKinds);

            if (queryResult.ExtendedError != null)
            {
                // The user may be offline or there might be some other server failure.
                return;
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, StoreProduct> item in queryResult.Products)
            {
                // Access the Store product info for the add-on.
                StoreProduct product = item.Value;

                // Use members of the product object to access listing info for the add-on...
            }
        }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the add-ons come.
MS say the delay will be one hour, or more.

And after one hour, i saw them in the store. And then i think i can get them using code.

**But, due to system delay, it costs 24 hours to really take effect.**